# почему и как методы StringBuilder могут изменять private final поле через геттер?

Tags: java

почему и как методы StringBuilder могут изменять private final поле?

```
public class Employee {

    private final StringBuilder name = new StringBuilder("value");

    public StringBuilder getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        var employee = new Employee();

        System.out.println(employee.getName());

        employee.getName().append("1");

        System.out.println(employee.getName());
    }
}
```

вывод: value
value1

как так?

Comment: `final` говорит о том, что вы не сможете потом в коде сделать `name = new StringBuilder();` - менять "внутренности" `name` при этом не запрещается. А то что `private` - так за счет `public` get-метода это поле благополучно торчит наружу

Comment: @Regent таки вопрос. смысл в приватном поле, если мы может его любым паблик методом изменить?

Comment: В представленном коде - да, смысла не видно. Я бы в данном случае ожидал метод `public String getName() { return name.toString(); }` - это и инкапсуляция  (никто снаружи не знает и не зависит от того, как на самом деле хранится `name`), и целостность данных (невозможно снаружи поменять значение `name`). В качестве минуса такого подхода - это преобразование и копирование возвращаемых данных, но в определённых ситуациях это вполне себе адекватная плата за инкапсуляцию и целостность

Comment: @Regent я вас понял, благодарю.